# How do I remove one or more names from the title on my car in California

Tags: united-states, car, california, liability, title

I am trying to remove my sister's name from my car which currently has my name and her's on the title. I can't seem to find information on this at the dmv website apart from Notice of Transfer and Release of liability. Do I do need to change ownership? Or is there a specific form to fill out in order to remove my sister's name from the title of the car.

Comment: Is the car owned outright (you have the pink slip/title) or is it still owned by a bank?

Comment: owned outright, yes I do have the pink slip/title form. Only question I got is how do I remove a name off of it seeing as my sister has her own car now.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow these instructions at the [California DMV page](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/howto/htvr32) and transfer the title. Depending on whether you and your sister are titled with AND/OR, you may need her signature to transfer ownership to yourself only. There is a $15 fee and the car needs to be able to pass emissions, etc. This is the exact same process as you would go through to sell the car elsewhere.

Comment: "and the car needs to be able to pass emissions, etc." Family transfers are exempt from smog inspection; I believe this would be a family transfer, because one of the sellers is a sibling (which is an eligible family member), and the other seller is the buyer themself.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this twice in my life. Once when removing my mom from a my first car once I had finished paying the loan (she co-signed for me) and once when assuming ownership of my grandpa's car after he passed.

The transaction is no different than a plain vanilla sale in the eyes of the CA DMV.  In your case both owners would fill out the current pink slip and release of liability.  You then fill out the transfer of ownership, transferring ownership to yourself.  You and your sister are both the sellers, and you alone are the buyer.

Comment: "like smog" Family transfers are exempt from smog inspection. I believe all the cases you mentioned are family transfers.

Comment: I could swear I had to smog the second one, but that must have just coincided with the registration...

Comment: @quid Or the clerk who did the transfer didn't know it was a family transfer, or grandparent-grandchild is not 'eligible' family.